# nginx set remaining count for limit_req in X-RateLimit-Remaining header

Tags: nginx, server, devops

I'm actually a little surprised that I couldn't find anything after a couple hours of googling, but the problem is as follows:

I want nginx to serve as my throttle for my API.

My config file contains a well-cited example of `limit_req_zone`:

`limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=limit:2m rate=10r/m;`

along with my `location` directive containing the expected `limit_req zone=limit nodelay;`

I would love to have nginx attach headers to the response message for both the `X-RateLimit-Remaining` and `X-RateLimit-Reset` attributes.  Basically have nginx use the active count of the `rate=10r/m` to populate `X-RateLimit-Remaining` and timeframe of the same `rate=10r/m` value to populate `X-RateLimit-Reset` with how many seconds are left before a refresh.

```
http {
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=login:10m rate=2r/s;
    limit_req_status 429;
    limit_conn_status 429;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  [removed];

        location / {
            limit_req zone=limit nodelay;

            proxy_pass http://reverse-proxy-example;
            add_header  X-RateLimit-Remaining [nginx variable?];
            add_header  X-RateLimit-Reset [nginx variable?]
        }
}
```

Thoughts?  Possible?  Would love to avoid hitting the application to get these numbers.

Comment: FWIW I grepped the NGinx source code and couldn't find any references to Remaining or Reset values.

Comment: I know some frameworks have built in rate limiting, but think about that, we have to pass the requests to the app, load / execute the code, make connections to redis just to track ratelimit params. It would be much better to handle it at the server level, especially with NGinx's better and built-in memory management.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that this isn't possible with the upstream version of nginx.

You can find the documentation for the `limit_req` directive through http://nginx.org/r/limit_req, which redirects to http://nginx.org/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html#limit_req, which conclusively shows that the module doesn't have any known variables within it.

Looking at http://ngx.su/src/http/modules/ngx_http_limit_req_module.c confirms the conjecture.

Another option is to look at http://nginx.org/docs/varindex.html, which lists all the variables — looking for `limit` will only get you to `$limit_rate`, which is an unrelated variable.

---

P.S. Consider that the `limit_req` is done through a *leaky bucket* method.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket

Without going into further details or making stuff up (the wikipedia article is huge!), I'd guess that it may not be entirely trivial to present this information to the end user in a consistent and actionable manner.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @cnst's answer, there is no an approprivate varible to save the value you want, if you really want the message, you can implement a lua function to save this message.
The nginx config would like this:

```
http {
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=login:10m rate=2r/s;
    limit_req_status 429;
    limit_conn_status 429;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  [removed];
        set $x-ratelimit-ramaining 0;
        set $x-ratelimit-reset 0;
        access_by_lua_file your_file_name.lua;

        location / {
            limit_req zone=limit nodelay;

            proxy_pass http://reverse-proxy-example;
            add_header  X-RateLimit-Remaining $x-rate-limit-remaining;
            add_header  X-RateLimit-Reset $x-ratelimit-reset;
        }
}
```

thus, each request will trigger the lua script, and you can update the variables `$x-rate-limit-remaining` `$x-ratelimit-reset` in your lua function.

Answer (score -5):

[Packngo](https://github.com/packethost/packngo/blob/master/packngo.go) from [Packet](https://www.packet.net/) has a function that might be a good fit for what you need to do.

Sample from packngo:

```
func (r *Response) populateRate() {
    // parse the rate limit headers and populate Response.Rate
    if limit := r.Header.Get(headerRateLimit); limit != "" {
        r.Rate.RequestLimit, _ = strconv.Atoi(limit)
    }
    if remaining := r.Header.Get(headerRateRemaining); remaining != "" {
        r.Rate.RequestsRemaining, _ = strconv.Atoi(remaining)
    }
    if reset := r.Header.Get(headerRateReset); reset != "" {
        if v, _ := strconv.ParseInt(reset, 10, 64); v != 0 {
            r.Rate.Reset = Timestamp{time.Unix(v, 0)}
        }
    }
}
```